# Powershell do while loop script output unexpected

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

Trying to get the active processes for powershell(example) after every 5 seconds. Running the below script. I killed 2 powershell sessions and the script which is running every 5 seconds doesn't update the active sessions as 3 instead it displays as 5 sessions. please help me where am going wrong

```
$process = Get-Process powershell* 
$count = $process.count 
Do {
    $count
    sleep -Seconds 5 
} until ($count -eq 1)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to put your first two statements inside your `do` block.

```
do 
{
    $process = Get-Process powershell*
    $count = $process.count
    $count
    sleep -Seconds 5
} until ($count -eq 1)
```

that way you recalculate `$count` each time you loop, otherwise the value never changes as you observed.